# Get Linux Kernel module name from current module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm writing some kernel modules, but for debug output I'd like to (automatically) print out which kernel module is producing the output. Is there a function or variable I can use to get the name of the module that's executing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the code of the kernel module, `THIS_MODULE` points to the structure representing this module. You may use `name` field of this structure for extract the current module name:

```
printk("Current module name: %s\n", THIS_MODULE->name);
```

If your code could be compiled (depending on configuration) either as a **module** or as a **part of the kernel**, then in the latter case `THIS_MODULE` will be NULL, so you cannot access its fields. For such code you could use `module_name` macro instead:

```
printk("Current module name: %s\n", module_name(THIS_MODULE));
```

Within the kernel core code (not a module) the macro is expanded to the string `"kernel"`.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that, I was actually looking around for `struct module` variables in that same file.